# PHP Curl - modify cookie instead of adding new one

Tags: php, curl, cookies

I got open curl session, that has cookie files set, so it would remember session id (from logging in). But how do I now modify those cookies?

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Cookie:blabla=bleble'));
```

Does not seem to act correctly, as it adds another `Cookie` header, so if for example I had between request headers:

```
...
Cookie:blabla=uhuhu;tralala=ahahaha
...
```

And I run this:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Cookie:blabla=bleble'));
```

It will simply add another `Cookie` header with same variable but different value:

```
...
Cookie:blabla=uhuhu;tralala=ahahaha
...
Cookie:blabla=bleble
```

So how do I modify existing Cookies instead of adding another `Cookie` header?

For example, when I login to site, keep session cookies in file, and in second request would like to replace it, I get something like this (being send):

**When replacing by `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER`**

**`curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, 'Cookie: 46db1eb1/sessid=blabla; 46db1eb1/zoom-accessibility=small');`**

```
POST /sysbus/NeMo/Intf/data:setFirstParameter HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.1) Gecko/20061204 Firefox/2.0.0.1
Host: 192.168.1.1
Accept: */*
Cookie: 46db1eb1/sessid=YHGDba31faykfyTJraQMewP+
Content-Type:application/x-sah-ws-1-call+json; charset=UTF-8
X-Context:n1psjUEjqs5j7Bb5vvT0J3wXMunQ2e8c3ksb5Uikcdt9Ct1XOJUmAh8azkOqmMqe
X-Prototype-Version:1.7
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Referer:http://192.168.1.1/advConfigAccessType.html
Cookie:46db1eb1/sessid=blabla; 46db1eb1/zoom-accessibility=small
Content-Length: 73
```

As you can see - cookies are doubled.

**When replacing with `CURLOPT_COOKIE`**

**`curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIE, '46db1eb1/sessid=blabla; 46db1eb1/zoom-accessibility=small');`**

```
POST /sysbus/NeMo/Intf/data:setFirstParameter HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.1) Gecko/20061204 Firefox/2.0.0.1
Host: 192.168.1.1
Accept: */*
Cookie: 46db1eb1/sessid=FHjCFhn/VKgkC09y7772fXpp; 46db1eb1/sessid=blabla; 46db1eb1/zoom-accessibility=small
Content-Type:application/x-sah-ws-1-call+json; charset=UTF-8
X-Context:VCtJDc4PrVjybyFcw8jGAc3anO5mXm7GPnfgn8VES54TqwUKr4fP68PhJHtuSn2x
X-Prototype-Version:1.7
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Referer:http://192.168.1.1/advConfigAccessType.html
Content-Length: 73
```

Values are doubled in same cookie header.

**curl 7.26.0, Raspbian (Debian 7.8)**

Comment: Which system? I cannot reproduce it on Mac with PHP 5.5 and curl 7.37

Comment: Also tested on Ubuntu with PHP 5.5 + curl 7.35 - last `curl_setopt` overwrites previous cookie header

Comment: curl 7.26.0 (arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf) libcurl/7.26.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1e zlib/1.2.7 libidn/1.25 libssh2/1.4.2 librtmp/2.3 on Raspbian (Debian 7.8). Are you sure it overwrites it? Did u get the cookie from site instead of manually set it at first time?

Comment: Comments are slightly limited,  please see my answer how I tested.

Answer (score 0):

You can manipulate the `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` file. Something like this:

```
<?php
function init($f)
{
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost/a.php");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $f);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $f);
    return $curl;
}
function readCookies($f)
{
    $cookies = [];
    if (($handle = fopen($f, "r")) !== FALSE) {
        while (($cookie = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, "\t")) !== FALSE) {
            $cookies[] = $cookie;
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
    return $cookies;
}
function writeCookies($f, $c)
{
    $fp = fopen($f, "w");

    foreach ($c as $cookie) {
        fputcsv($fp, $cookie, "\t");
    }

    fclose($fp);
}

$f = './c.tmp';
$curl = init($f);
curl_exec($curl);

// playing with cookies:
$newCookie = ['blabla', '123'];
$cookies = readCookies($f);
if (!empty($cookies)) {
    $found = false;
    foreach($cookies as $key=>$val) {
        // ignore comments and empty lines
        if (count($val) == 7) {
            if ($val[5] == $newCookie[0]) {
                $found = $key;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if ($found) {
        $cookies[$found][6] = $newCookie[1];
    } else {
        // I am using first one as a template,
        // but you may need to set all fields explicitly
        // as they may differ
        $cookie = $cookies[0];
        $cookie[5] = $newCookie[0];
        $cookie[6] = $newCookie[1];
        $cookies[] = $cookie;
    }
    writeCookies($f, $cookies);
}

$curl = init($f);
if (empty($cookies)) {
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Cookie:blabla=123'));
}
curl_exec($curl);
```

Comment: Maybe PHP interpretates that this way... but could you please check directly what CURL sends? Like this: `$headerSent = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT);print_r($headerSent);`

Comment: Indeed. Checked with tcpdump, it does send multiple cookie headers =(. I updated the answer with possible solution.